# why the submit button doesn't work?

Tags: html, forms

My code is a simple HTML form with a button for `edit password`.  I tried to make it work in PHP, but it doesn't do anything after entering facebook.com as an action.

Here is the code:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="https://www.facebook.com" method="POST">
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Current Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Password" name="Current Password" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your current password." >
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" name="New Password" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your new password." >
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Re-enter Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter Password" name="Re-enter Password" id="name"required data-validation-required-message="Please re-enter your password." >
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button  class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" style="padding:10px 20px;width:100px;" type="submit">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" style="padding:10px 20px;width:100px;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is URL at `action` expecting cross-origin `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just post values to www.facebook.com or any other website because their is no code on these websites to receive values that you posted.

Comment: i just put facebook.com for testing if the button does any action or not and it does not do anything

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow cross origin request, you better read about cross origin request.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to post something at facebook.com? If this is what you want, you can't do that. Secured websites especially facebook do not just allow random submitions of POST or GET requests on their site.

Comment: no ,of course that's not i want to
i just put facebook.com for testing if the button do any action or not
and it does not do anything

Comment: I used your exact code and then use javascript to submit the form. The form submitted, I was redirected to facebook.com saying that "Request could not be processed". So in short, the form was able to submit a request to facebook but it will just redirect to the site. No further actions will happen

Comment: could you tell me how do you use javascript to submit the form?

Comment: var test = document.getElementById('contactForm');
test.submit();

After this. Submit worked.